# error C2039: “SetDefaultDllDirectories”:is not a member of global namespace

Tags: mfc

xxx\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h(638): error C2039: “SetDefaultDllDirectories”: is not a member of "global namespace"

```
#ifndef _USING_V110_SDK71_
    // the LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32 flag for LoadLibraryExW is only supported if the DLL-preload fixes are installed, so
    // use LoadLibraryExW only if SetDefaultDllDirectories is available (only on Win8, or with KB2533623 on Vista and Win7)...
    IFDYNAMICGETCACHEDFUNCTION(L"kernel32.dll", SetDefaultDllDirectories, pfSetDefaultDllDirectories)
    {
        return(::LoadLibraryExW(pszLibrary, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32));
    }
#endif
```

the functions in it are all not realized by VS
so how do I solve this problem?
is there something wrong with the libray?I run this program in VS2012

Answer (score 9):

You have to make sure "_USING_V110_SDK71_" is defined in your project properties.  Visual Studio automatically defines this for you.  It normally doesn't "show up" because "Inherit from parent or project defaults" is un-ticked.

I've found this common when upgrade from old atl projects that the stdafx.cpp has "Inherit from parent or project defaults" un-ticked for some reason.

You should check both the project settings as well as the individual stdafx.cpp file settings to determine that in the Preprocessor Definitions the "Inherit from parent or project defaults" check box is checked. In some cases the Preprocessor Definitions dialog of the Project file is checked however the Preprocessor Definitions dialog of the specific stdafx.cpp file is NOT checked.

Comment: If the C/C++ and Resource Preprocessor Definitions are customized in the project property page, make sure they end in __;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)__. That caused an issue with an undefined __\_USING_V110_SDK71\___ symbol for a project migrated from VS2005 to VS2010 and now VS2015 -- this was missing for the x86/x64 Debug configurations but not the release configurations.

Comment: "Inherit from parent or project defaults" tickbox controls if ";%(PreprocessorDefinitions)" is there or not.  If you add/remove this manually, you will find tickbox changes.  It's easier to check the tickbox than it is to remember ";%(PreprocessorDefinitions)" :)

Comment: Ah yes, I see. You have to select Edit from the dropdown in the Preprocessor Definitions to see that.  I thought you were referring to the "<Inherit from parent or Project Defaults>" item in the dropdown, which wipes out the customizations.  I didn't drill deep enough and sure enough, checking/unchecking the box causes ;%(PreprocessorDefinitions) to be added and removed.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the order of Include Directories and included SDK folder works for me:
`$(IncludePath);C:\Program Files x86\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include`

If I put folder `C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include` before `$(IncludePath)`, I will get this error.

Answer (score 4):

I also met this issue on VS 2012.

This is caused because you are using the Windows SDK 7.1 which lacks of `SetDefaultDllDirectories` function call in *VS 2012* (VC11). You may notice there is `#ifndef _USING_V110_SDK71_` guarded flag to avoid using undefined `SetDefaultDllDirectories`.

Just define `_USING_V110_SDK71_` in your project to let SDK knows you are in this toolset or upgrade to higher version of SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem using VS2008, it was not recognizing a function. I solved it by adding DDX_Control to the DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX).

Answer (score 0):

1. Put following lines in include above all

   `$(VC_IncludePath)`
   `$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)`
2. Uncheck check box "inherit from parent or project defaults"

Answer (score 0):

I   copy  _USING_V110_SDK71_ in part C/C++ in  sub branch preprocessor / preprocessor definition and once unchech inherit from parent ... and do build project and  then recheck this option and solved problem

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue . this trick work for me. this issue comes when visual studio can't load development environment properly . can't load environment variables. so I have tried this and it works fine.

Step #1

Start command prompt of visual studio which you are using

Step #2
run this command .

```
devenv /useenv
```

this command will open visual studio and then open your project and compile.