# Visual Studio 2013: error C2039: 'SetDefaultDllDirectories' : is not a member of '`global namespace''

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

Upon upgrading C++ project from VS10 to VS13 I am facing 3 errors:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h(637): error C2039: 'SetDefaultDllDirectories'
- error C2065: 'SetDefaultDllDirectories' : undeclared identifier.
- error C2065: 'LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32' : undeclared identifier.

'SetDefaultDllDirectories' and 'LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32' are defined in 'c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\libloaderapi.h'.

The path 'c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um' is specified in the "Include Directories" list of my project properties, and yet - those errors are showed up.

Platform Toolset V120 is set to this project.

Thanks

Comment: are you including "LibLoaderAPI.h" and do you have  `_WIN32_WINNT` defined to Windows 8 or better (for earlier Windows versions you have to `GetProcAddress`, according to the docs)

Comment: @Cheers
The header file "LibLoaderApi.h" is inside 'c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um', which is specified in "Include Directories" list of my project. Is there anywhere else I should define it in?
I don't really understand where should I define _WIN32_WINNT and what is the meaning of GetProcAddress...What do you mean by docs?which ones?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (MSDN Library). `_WIN32_WINNT` is a macro that you define before including `<windows.h>`, e.g. in the project properties. Roughly, it determines the highest supported version of the Windows API; functions introduced later will generally not be declared.

Comment: See [error C2039: “SetDefaultDllDirectories”:is not a member of global namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698882/error-c2039-setdefaultdlldirectories-is-not-a-member-of-global-namespace) which has some answers.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue . this trick work for me. this issue comes when visual studio can't load development environment properly . can't load environment variables. so I have tried this and it works fine.

Step #1

Start command prompt of visual studio which you are using

Step #2
run this command .

```
devenv /useenv
```

this command will open visual studio and then open your project and compile.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? The cause of the error and the solution are not clear at all in what you say.

Comment: I guess this would help enrich your answer. You also could format it for quicker reading.