# _USING_V110_SDK71_ not inherited from defaults in VC++ 2015, v140_xp, Release?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, sdk, atl, visual-c++-2015

**Summary:** Undeclared identifier `SetDefaultDllDirectories` from `atlcore.h` is reported when compiling the Release version, but it is OK when compiling Debug. Further investigation shows that the `_USING_V110_SDK71_` plays the role. It should be inherited from the project defaults (see picture below), but it is not for the combination: Release MinDependency, and v140_xp.

**Details:** I am migrating the C++ native, ATL application from Visual C++ 2005 to Visual C++ 2015. The goal is to keep the Windows XP running version as long as possible. Therefore, the v140_xp Platform Toolset was set for the project. It works fine for the Debug version. However, it causes compilation error for Release MinDepency version. When using v140 (without _xp), it compiles fine.

This is a branch of the application that needs to be migrated. I have already successfully migrated other branches (earlier) to VC++ 2008, 2010, 2012, and 2013. (Or I forgot to do something, or the situation is different now.)

I have seen that error [also mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16698882/1346705); however, the reasons may be different. The full error line is:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h(644):
error C2065: 'SetDefaultDllDirectories':undeclared identifier
```

The problematic lines are used for the case when

```
#ifndef _USING_V110_SDK71_
```

So, apparently that symbol was not defined. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional, version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL, and Windows 8.1.

When checking the project settings, the `_USING_V110_SDK71_` symbol should be defined -- inherited from project defaults.

[image: _USING_V110_SDK71_ should be defined!?]

**Update:** The error message and the lines around in the Output window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Market, Configuration: Release MinDependency Win32 ------
1>  SplashScreen.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\sal_supp.h(57): warning C4005: '__useHeader': macro redefinition
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\sal.h(2886): note: see previous definition of '__useHeader'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\specstrings_supp.h(77): warning C4005: '__on_failure': macro redefinition
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\sal.h(2896): note: see previous definition of '__on_failure'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h(644): error C2039: 'SetDefaultDllDirectories': is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h(644): error C2065: 'SetDefaultDllDirectories': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcore.h(646): error C2065: 'LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32': undeclared identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\wtl90\include\atlgdi.h(470): warning C4838: conversion from 'int' to 'UINT' requires a narrowing conversion
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\wtl90\include\atlgdi.h(477): warning C4838: conversion from 'int' to 'UINT' requires a narrowing conversion
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\wtl90\include\atlgdi.h(484): warning C4838: conversion from 'int' to 'UINT' requires a narrowing conversion
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\wtl90\include\atlgdi.h(491): warning C4838: conversion from 'int' to 'UINT' requires a narrowing conversion
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\wtl90\include\atlgdi.h(3683): warning C4838: conversion from 'LONG' to 'DWORD' requires a narrowing conversion
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Could you shed some light on that? Thanks

Comment: Hard to guess, everything looks normal.  Your Output window does not, seems it is complaining about something else as well.  Avoid cherry-picking errors.

Comment: Thanks Hans -- the Update contains the messages now. Can it be caused by the combination with the v7.1a Windows SDK? But why it works with Debug and fails with Release?

Comment: Those warnings are also caused by the missing macro.  You'll have to dig deeper and check what is actually passed to the compiler.  Or just punt the problem and define the macro yourself. Or just get rid of configuration completely, MinDependency was retired several versions ago.

Comment: I tried to define the macro on my own in the Project properties (that is not relying on "Inherit...". But it behaves the same way. I can see in the vcxproj that it is a mixture of older things with new things. How can I reliably throw away the old things and create the fresh ones? Should I erase the solution file and the project file and create it from scratch "... from existing sources"?

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for the hint to re-create the project from scratch. Please, copy that comment as answer. I would like to accept it and to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you converted the project files from a prior version of Visual Studio, it's possible that some build settings (including the preprocessor macro definitions) were emitted into each individual file's configuration settings.  To check for this, right-click a source file and hit Properties, then navigate to the preprocessor tab.  If you see bolded text in the Preprocessor Definitions field, then you'll know that this was your culprit.  To fix it, you'll need to have each file inherit from the project settings, which can be tedious; I find it easiest to load up the vcxproj in a text editor and strip away the offending definitions.

Comment: Thanks, Bekenn. The project has about 300 .cpp files, so I cannot do that. I have already created the project from scratch as HansPassant suggested.